# Average distance of two points in unit n-dimensional hypercube

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, random

An easy way to understand the unit n-dimensional hypercube is to consider the region of space in n dimensions that you can get if every coordinate component lies in [0, 1]. So for one dimension it's the line segment from 0 to 1, for two dimensions it's the square with corners (0, 0) and (1, 1), etc.

Write a program or function that given *n* returns the average Euclidean distance of two points uniformly random selected from the unit n-dimension hypercube. Your answer **must** be within 10<sup>-6</sup> of the actual value. It's ok if your answer overflows your language's native floating point type for big n.

***Randomly* selecting a 'big' number of points and calculating the average does not guarantee such accuracy.**

Examples:

> 1 → 0.3333333333...
>   2 → 0.5214054331...
>   3 → 0.6617071822...
>   4 → 0.7776656535...
>   5 → 0.8785309152...
>   6 → 0.9689420830...
>   7 → 1.0515838734...
>   8 → 1.1281653402...

<sup>Data acquired from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubeLinePicking.html).</sup>

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: Reiterated winning criterion in an edit.

Comment: Just to be clear: *distance* refers to the Euclidean distance, yes?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, I will add that.

Comment: @orlp can you post the formula used? Or is there no generic formula? https://martin-thoma.com/average-distance-of-points/ Beta function here seems like what you want, but they only give pseudo code.

Comment: @carusocomputing What's the point of the challenge if you want me to solve it for you?

Comment: Is it OK to use a Monte Carlo method to have a failure probability of at most, say, 10^-10?

Comment: @xnor No. Your answer __must__ be accurate to at least 5 decimals.

Comment: @orlp I consider that a strange interpretation, since it's easy to an indisinguishable random program with negligible failure chance. It's your challenge though, and you should make it extremely clear you're banning this method to make sure posters don't waste time trying it.

Comment: @orlp registering my objection to a challenge that is a math puzzle until someone figures out the math, then it becomes a programming puzzle when everyone copies the formula in different languages. I need to ask a meta question about this.

Comment: @Sparr There are dozens of various methods of evaluating integrals (oops, spoiler alert). I don't believe there's a known formula that you can just implement and everyone will copy it. Even if that were the case, I don't see the problem. There are multiple aspects to solving a challenge, and golfing the syntax is only one of those.

Comment: Is it OK if the algorithm has a ridiculous runtime if the final answer is guaranteed accurate?

Comment: @xnor Per default PPCG rules, yes.

Comment: When you say 5 digits of accuracy, do you mean to within 1e-5, or would an estimate of 1.500000000000001 be wrong when the output should be 1.499999999999999?

Comment: @xnor 5 digits should be accurate, _after rounding_. So `1.49999999999` rounds to `1.50000`.

Comment: @orlp That still doesn't preclude an arbitrarily small error from giving different first 5 digits. Please give accuracy requirements in terms of a relative error.

Comment: @feersum Why relative error? I edited to absolute error within 10^-6.

Comment: Then the allowed relative errors goes to 0 as n -> infinity.

Comment: The result diverges as the number of dimensions approaches infinity, correct?

Comment: @mbomb007 I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 68 bytes

```
NIntegrate[(1-((E^-u^2+u*Erf@u√π-1)/u^2)^#)/u^2,{u,0,∞}]/√π&
```

Implementation of the formula using `NIntegrate` to approximate its value.

[image]

Comment: Beat me by 58 seconds :(

Comment: Where did you find the formula?

Comment: @feersum It's formula (8) from [Hypercube Line Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubeLinePicking.html). (10) is a typo and shouldn't have the double integral or du.

Comment: If you actually input this as text it parses `u√π` as one token, so you need a space between `u` and `√`.